# select both nested and not nested fields from a data.frame in R

Tags: r, select, dataframe, nested

Is it posible to select both nested and not nested fields from a data.frame?

For example:

```
df=data.frame(
     a=c(1,2,3)
    ,b=c(4,5,6)
)
nested=data.frame(
     a=c(10,20,30)
    ,b=c(40,50,60)
)
df$nested=nested

print(df)
#   a b nested.a nested.b
#   1 4       10       40
#   2 5       20       50
#   3 6       30       60
```

I know I can select not nested fields this way

```
df[,c("a","b")] 
#   a b
#   1 4
#   2 5
#   3 6
```

and nested fields this other way

```
df$nested[,c("a","b")] 
#    a  b
#   10 40
#   20 50
#   30 60
```

I would like to do sometihng like this:

```
df_new=df[,c("a","nested$a")]
#    a  nested.a
#    1 10
#    2 20
#    3 30
```

Answer (score 0):

We could `unnest` it by converting to `data.frame` within `do.call` and then select the column names as below

```
do.call(data.frame, df)[c('a', 'nested.a')]
#   a nested.a
#1 1       10
#2 2       20
#3 3       30
```